# Connect bluetooth headphones both to PC and phone at the same time

Tags: connection, bluetooth, mobile-phone

I have recently bought [Philips SHB6110](http://www.consumer.philips.com/c/cell-phone-accessories/shb6110_97/prd/in/). Extract from the 13th page of [manual](http://www.p4c.philips.com/files/s/shb6110_97/shb6110_97_dfu_aen.pdf):

> Therefore you can connect your
>   Bluetooth stereo headset.
>
> - with a Bluetooth stereo enabled phone    to both listen to music and
>     lead    calls, or
> - with a Bluetooth phone that    does not support Bluetooth stereo    (A2DP)
>     to lead calls and at the same    time
>     to a Bluetooth audio device
>     (Bluetooth enabled MP3 player,
>     Bluetooth audio adapter etc.) to
>     listen to music. Make sure to pair
>     the phone first with your Bluetooth
>     headset, then turn both the phone and 
>     headset off to then pair the
>     Bluetooth audio device.
>
> With the SwitchStream feature you can
>   listen to music and monitor your calls
>   at the same time. Even while listening
>   to music, you will hear a ring tone
>   when receiving a call and can switch
>   to the call simply by tapping the
>   button.

The manual however doesn't specify how do I connect to both device at the same time. I use [Toshiba Satellite Pro P300-1CG](http://www.dooyoo.co.uk/laptops/toshiba-satellite-pro-p300-1cg/) laptop with [Belkin Mini Bluetooth Adapter](http://www.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=398674) and [Nokia N95](http://www.nokia.co.uk/support/product-support/nokia-n95) phone. Operating system is Windows 7 64-bit and I have Skype installed.

Both phone and compute can be used for listening to music and talking on the phone (on PC via Skype). Best solution would be if I could connect to PC and phone as the same time and monitor calls both mobile and Skype calls while listening music from Winamp. If that is not possible, then I would like at least to be able to listen music from PC, while monitoring calls from mobile.

So, please tell me how do I connect both PC and phone to headphones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rereading the manual once again, noticed the following: "with a Bluetooth phone that **does not support** Bluetooth stereo (A2DP)". Therefore my phone will not allow to connect to the second device.

Answer (score 2):

I did this today, by pairing the phone to my laptop, and then the headset to the laptop. Was able to hear phone audio on the bluetooth headphones. YMMV though, seems like it was a bit choppy at times to be streaming from/to both devices.

Comment: Wow! I would have probably never even tried something like this if you didn't tell me. However, I found out that in order to use the feature described in the manual my phone has to connect to headphones only via HSP protocol and so far I have found no way to restrict my phone to do so (it always connects both A2DP and HSP) .

Comment: +1 "Never say never :)"... It is inspiring to read explanations of "how can I do X / You cannot do X because Y" after someone has done X, even when Y is 100% true.

Comment: how exactly did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

It may be impossible to do this. See if there is more in the manual about this bluetooth device being a "master bluetooth" device or not

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth

You can get more info. there. Some devices can only connect to one device at a time.