# Issue With Script To Reconnect Bluetooth Device (Bluetooth Command Line Tools)

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, bluetooth

I've set up the following script:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Bluetooth Command Line Tools\bin\btcom" -b "38:b1:9e:e7:35:9d" -c -s111e
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Bluetooth Command Line Tools\bin\btcom" -b "38:b1:9e:e7:35:9d" -c -s110b
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Bluetooth Command Line Tools\bin\btcom" -n "Marathon" -c -s111e
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Bluetooth Command Line Tools\bin\btcom" -n "Marathon" -c -s110b
```

As suggested in this answer: [How can I script a bluetooth device to connect/disconnect?](https://superuser.com/questions/408302/how-can-i-script-a-bluetooth-device-to-connect-disconnect)

But for every line I'm getting the following error:

> System Error.  Code: 87.
>
> The parameter is incorrect

Any idea why this could be?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue (from the same source)

I use this when switching my headphones off my phone onto my pain-cave zwift computer.
At first it worked fine, now I get -87 and had to go back to switching in windows bluetooth control panel (which is a minor inconvenience!)

Seems that if I script it to do a -r followed by a -c for both services on the same address it works fine.

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Bluetooth Command Line Tools\bin\btcom.exe" -b "E4:22:A5:67:D0:49" -r -s110b
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Bluetooth Command Line Tools\bin\btcom.exe" -b "E4:22:A5:67:D0:49" -r -s111e
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Bluetooth Command Line Tools\bin\btcom.exe" -b "E4:22:A5:67:D0:49" -c -s110b
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Bluetooth Command Line Tools\bin\btcom.exe" -b "E4:22:A5:67:D0:49" -c -s111e
```

Comment: I confirm this worked in my case, too.